# How to know the real-time information(e.g. ISO, shutter speed) of android camera?

Tags: android, camera, real-time, getter

I want to make the camera app - it can get and display current ISO, shutter speed, aperture, and exposure value.

I tried to find to make, but failed because I can't find getter method of them.
If I search like "get current android camera" or something like that, the result is "set surrent android camera".
I also tried to find via Android API pages and NDK API, but I couldn't find this.

How to know the current information of android camera?

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and found a solution, but I am using Camera2 API, you are using Camera2?

Comment: from NDK ( camera 2 API only ), implemented from android-24, you might find some info: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/include/camera/ndk/NdkCameraMetadataTags.h